# Collect AVFrames into buffer

Tags: ffmpeg, memory-leaks

I'm collect AVFrames into array and then free them but this causes memory leak.

```cpp
extern "C" {
#include <libavutil/frame.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
}

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

AVFrame * createFrame() {
    int width = 1280;
    int height = 720;
    AVPixelFormat format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    int buffer_size = av_image_get_buffer_size(format, width, height, 1);
    uint8_t * buffer = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(uint8_t));
    memset(buffer, 1, buffer_size);

    uint8_t *src_buf[4];
    int      src_linesize[4];
    av_image_fill_arrays(src_buf, src_linesize, buffer, format, width, height, 1);

    AVFrame * frame = av_frame_alloc();
    frame->width = width;
    frame->height = height;
    frame->format = format;
    av_frame_get_buffer(frame, 0);
    av_image_copy(frame->data, frame->linesize,
                  const_cast<const uint8_t**>(src_buf), const_cast<const int*>(src_linesize),
                  format, width, height);
    av_free(buffer);
    return frame;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    uint32_t count = 1024;

    // fill array with frames
    std::vector<AVFrame*> list;
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        list.push_back(createFrame());
    }
    // allocated 1385 mb in heap

    // clear all allocated data
    for (auto i = list.begin(); i < list.end(); ++i) {
        if (*i != NULL) {
            av_frame_free(&(*i));
        }
    }
    list.clear();

    // memory-leak of > 360 Mb
}
```

But if just create frame and immediatly free it without saving it into vector, no memory leak, despite the fact that the same number of frames was created.

What i'm doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I was wrong. There is no memory leak here(checked by valgrind), but the freed memory does not immediately return to the operating system, this confused me.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use `av_image_fill_arrays` on newly allocated `AVFrame` like this:

```
av_image_fill_arrays(frame->data,       /* destination */
                     frame->linesize,   /* destination */
                     buffer,            /* source      */
                     format,            /* source      */
                     width,             /* source & alingment */
                     height, 1);
```

Get rid of unnecessay code above like manully copying buffer and do not use `av_free(buffer);` in the `createFrame` either. Function `av_image_fill_arrays` does not allocate any buffer. Just uses existing one; `av_frame_free` in `main()` will take care of freeing.

Here is some documentation:

> **av_image_fill_arrays**
>
> Setup the data pointers and linesizes based on the specified image
>   parameters and the provided array.
>
> The fields of the given image are filled in by using the src address
>   which points to the image data buffer. Depending on the specified
>   pixel format, one or multiple image data pointers and line sizes will
>   be set. If a planar format is specified, several pointers will be set
>   pointing to the different picture planes and the line sizes of the
>   different planes will be stored in the lines_sizes array. Call with
>   src == NULL to get the required size for the src buffer.
>
> To allocate the buffer and fill in the dst_data and dst_linesize in
>   one call, use av_image_alloc().

Hope that helps.

Comment: My code snippet above only for example, actually I get filled frames from decoder and save its to collection.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I encounter the same issue. After tracing the call stacks, I realized that ffmpeg uses link lists of `AVBufferPool`s to improve memory allocation and deallocation.

In the function body of `buffer_replace` which is called from `av_buffer_unref`, it calls the `free` function of the buffer:
`b->free(b->opaque, b->data)`. After step into this call, it jumps to `void pool_release_buffer(void *opaque, uint8_t *data)` in `buffer.c` file. You will see it really maintains a pool list for reusing allocated buffers.